# How to active responsive design mode in safari 5.1.7 version

Tags: safari, windows-10

I have install windows 10 on my desktop with safari 5.1.7 version

[image]

I want to use responsive design mode on this version, is there any way to resolve it

Hope for reply, thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can not use this mode in safari for Windows.

Latest Safari version for Windows is 5.1.7.

Responsive design mode was added in Safari 9.0 version, [see release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_9_0.html).